# Different process are running as PID 1 when running CMD/ENTRYPOINT in shell form when the base images is centos vs ubuntu:trusty

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Build and run an image using the below dockerfile.

Dockerfile1

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
ENTRYPOINT ping localhost
```

Now run the below command to see the processes running in the container.

```
docker exec -it <container> ps -ef
```

**PID 1 process is running /bin/sh -c ping localhost**

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 11:35 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh -c ping localhost
root         8     1  0 11:35 ?        00:00:00 ping localhost
root         9     0  0 11:35 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Now change **ONLY** the base image to centos:latest.

Modified Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:latest
ENTRYPOINT ping localhost
```

Build and run an image using the modified dockerfile.
Run the 'docker exec -it  ps -ef' command again.

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 11:32 ?        00:00:00 ping localhost
root         8     0  0 11:33 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

**But now PID 1 process is running 'ping localhost'**

This happen even when ENTRYPOINT is replaced with CMD.

I thought when using the shell form /bin/sh is the process with PID as 1 (both when ENTRYPOINT/CMN being used).

Any ideas why I am seeing a different behaviour **just** by changing the base image?

Comment: If I was going to guess it's because `/bin/sh` is a different shell on Ubuntu than on CentOS.  (`sh -c` implicitly doing an `exec` is slightly surprising to me, but only a little.)

Comment: Big plus 1 for the [mcve], made this problem easy to reproduce and debug on my side. And a good question, hadn't noticed this behavior until now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the behavior of `bash`. Docker is still running the command with a shell which you can identify with an inspect:

```
$ docker inspect test-centos-entrypoint --format '{{.Config.Entrypoint}}'
[/bin/sh -c ping localhost]
```

You can see the version of /bin/sh (note the GNU bash part):

```
$ docker exec -it quicktest /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.                               
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

The ubuntu version of /bin/sh (possibly dash) doesn't even support the `--version` flag and is not linked to bash. But if you change the ubuntu image to use bash instead of /bin/sh, you'll see the behavior matching centos:

```
$ cat df.ubuntu-entrypoint
FROM ubuntu:trusty
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "ping localhost" ]

$ DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0 docker build -t test-ubuntu-entrypoint -f df.ubuntu-entrypoint .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.04kB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:trusty
 ---> 67759a80360c
Step 2/2 : ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "ping localhost" ]
 ---> Running in 5c4161cafd6b
Removing intermediate container 5c4161cafd6b
 ---> c871fe2e2063
Successfully built c871fe2e2063
Successfully tagged test-ubuntu-entrypoint:latest

$ docker run -d --name quicktest2 --rm test-ubuntu-entrypoint
362bdc75e4a960854ff17cf5cae62a3247c39079dc1290e8a85b88114b6af694

$ docker exec -it quicktest2 ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 13:05 ?        00:00:00 ping localhost
root         8     0  0 13:05 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

Comment: If my understanding is right, the difference between "exec" form and "shell" form is... Using the "exec" format, the entrypoint/command is run as PID 1, and there is no sh -c process, while using "shell" sh -c (which in centos is symlink to bash) is PID 1

Comment: Thinking a lot more, I think you are right. But this whole example is messing up my understanding of which process is run as PID 1 in "shell" vs "exec" from. Even if /bin/sh is merely a symlink in centos I expect it to still run (bash) as PID 1 and spawn a new bash shell to run the entrypoint command when using "shell" form. May be I'm wrong.

Comment: @I_JA it did run the shell in pid 1. The bash version of the shell is just behaving differently, running an exec on the command instead of forking a child pid.

Comment: yeh it appeared so. David Maze also seems to suggest so. Thanks to you both for clearing my understanding. I'm marking your answer as accepted, Thanks.